# Set up environment for cross-compilation to i386, armel, armhf, arm64 and mips with no libglib2 conflicts

Tags: debian, chroot, cross-compilation, multiarch

I'm trying to set up a build environment for a software package in Debian Jessie. I need to produce amd64, i386 and eventually armel and armhf binaries of the software. It would be cool if I could cross-compile it to ALL of the architectures supported by Debian, which are a lot more than that, but those 4 are the ones I particularly care about.

I started with amd64 Debian Jessie and added i386 multiarch.

It all worked well until I had to install `libpulse-dev`, which is a dependency of the software. When installing it, I got

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: libpulse-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed

with `apt-get` and

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: libglib2.0-dev : Conflicts: libglib2.0-dev:i386 but 2.42.1-1 is installed.

with `aptitude`.

It looks like `libglib2:amd64` and `libglib2:i386` conflict — they can't be installed at the same time. Someone on `#debian` at Freenode told me that it's a well-known limitation of multiarch.

I have to have that package installed in order to make i386 builds.

I'm thinking of removing i386 multiarch, since it doesn't work, and setting up i386 chroot and building the i386 version of the software inside that chroot.

That chroot solution should work for i386, but it doesn't work for when I will be producing binaries for armel, armhf, arm64, mips and all others architectures — I won't be able to make those builds in armel, armhf, arm64, mips, etc. chroots since I can't run arm and mips executables on my processor.

How can I produce builds of the software that target amd64, i386, armel, armhf, arm64 and mips architectures on the same Debian Jessie system in a consistent manner (i.e. all builds are done the same way, not "builds for one architecture use chroot, but builds for other architectures use multiarch") without getting `libglib2` conflicts like I do when using multiarch?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `glib2.0` isn't multiarch-compliant (yet); you can subscribe to https://bugs.debian.org/648621 if you want to keep an eye on things.

To build software for various architectures you can use [`pbuilder`](https://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks) and/or [`qemubuilder`](https://wiki.debian.org/qemubuilder). Debian has very good support for chroots using Qemu to run binaries on different architectures; `debootstrap` supports this natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two approaches, do cross compilation with multiarch for dependencies but use a dedicated chroot for each target architecture.

This way you won't have as many problems with conflicts. I can't gaurantee that it will work for your package but it has a much better chance that trying to do all architectures under the same root filesystem.